# What happens, technically, when you create an IPA in Xcode?

Tags: ios, compilation, xcode5, app-store, ipa

10.9.4, Xcode 5.1.1, targeting iPads only.

When a developer is ready to submit an IPA to the App Store, you select **Product** -> **Archive** and follow the prompts.

On my MacBook Air, Core i5, with 4GB of RAM, this takes a lot of time (15 mins). It goes through a lot of compilation, several phases, 500+ files.

I assume what is happening here is that it is building for each platform, iPhone, iPad, iPad Retina, etc but I really don't know.

What happens during this phase, technically?

Are there ways to speed this process up?

Comment: FYI - every time you do a development build to your device or the simulator, an IPA is created. There's nothing too different when doing an archive.

Comment: From my experience, archiving is usually slower than the normal developer build. I think it compresses the media files too, which takes time. But 15 minutes seems too much, unless your app is really big.

Comment: @TiagoLira - Thanks normal compiling takes around 3-4 mins, not a huge app at all.

Comment: From a personal experience, 4GB of RAM is barely enough for development. 8GB makes an incredible difference.